# Drupal autocomplete limit number of character

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, jquery-autocomplete

In Drupal 7 website. I don't want to call ajax for autocomplete if entered string length is less than 3 characters.

I have written the Jquery like this

```
    $('#name').keyup( function( e ) {
        if( $.trim( $('#edit-enterprise-ids').val().length ) < 3){
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But it is not working, If I write alert(''); in place of return false it works.
But I don't want to have alert there.
Please help.

Comment: So what shoudl happen? Because right now your event handler function does just end. So nothing happening is to be expected.

Comment: Try using this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_limit. What particular field are you trying to limit? Text autocomplete or a View autocomplete for example.

Comment: @stevenw00 it works.. thak you :)

Comment: I've added it as an answer below. Mark it as an answer for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Autocomplete Limit module here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_limit